# Bootstrap 4 image cards covering card text

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create 3 simple image cards with captions in Bootstrap 4, but no matter how I attempt to do it, the image within the card takes up the entire card, covering the caption below it.

The cards should look just like the example as I am using the same code, just putting it in a row. The card text is there, but it is directly beneath the image. How can I get the card to be longer so that the images stay at the top and reveal the text below?

Here's Bootstrap's example card:

[image: Screenshot 1]

And here's what mine look like:

[image: Screenshot 2]

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md">
    <div class="card" style="width: 17rem;">
      <img src="https://imgur.com/n5SWWmR" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md">
    <div class="card" style="width: 17rem;">
      <img src="https://imgur.com/n5SWWmR" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md">
    <div class="card" style="width: 17rem;">
      <img src="https://imgur.com/n5SWWmR" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you upload your images to a public hosting site so the snippet can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md">
    <div class="card" style="width: 17rem;">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/n5SWWmR.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md">
    <div class="card" style="width: 17rem;">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/n5SWWmR.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md">
    <div class="card" style="width: 17rem;">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/n5SWWmR.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want it side by side then you just have to modify the grid layout to col-md-4 for each div.